# Laravel 5.4 How to fix 'No query results for model'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Whenever I try to access /skills/add through an anchor in another page I get this error

[image]

The anchor that redirects to this page(with GET method) is:

```
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" href="/skills/add">
        <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>
            Add
    </a>
```

Tried using `dd("test")`  to test it out but won't even work.

This are my routes for skills/add this:

```
Route::put('/skills/add', 'SkillsController@add');

Route::get('/skills/add', 'SkillsController@addIndex');
```

Here are my functions in SkillsController

```
public function addIndex() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('skills.add');
    } else {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}

public function add(Request $request) {
    /*Sets validation rules for Skill object*/
    $skillRules = [
        'name' => 'required|max:25|regex:/[1-9a-zA-Z ]\w*/',
    ];
    if (Skills::where('name', '=', $request->name)->count() > 0) {
        return redirect('/skills')->with('message', "EXISTS");
    }

    $validator = Validator::validate($request->all(), $skillRules);
    if ($validator == null) {
        $newSkill = new Skills;
        $newSkill->name = strtolower($request->name);
        $newSkill->save();
        return redirect('/skills')->with('message', "CREATED");
    }
}
```

the skills.add view is this

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <h1>Edit Skill</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/skills/add">
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                 Name:
                <input name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Skill</button>
            <a href="/skills"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What line is your code error?  If you comment out the `if (Skills::` lines does it work?

Comment: I don't get any error line in my files, posted the error at the beginning of the post. And no, it doesn't work. Even tried completely removing all the section of both functions and the error still persists. Also just to point out the `add` method would not be called until the button(within skills/add) is clicked.

Comment: The problem is that your Skills Controller file is not able to find the model Skills. Please check that it has been included in the Controller and also check the name space of the model Skills.

Comment: For model Skills: `namespace RampUp;` for SkillsController `use RampUp\Skills;`

Comment: Check `if (Skills::where('name', '=', $request->name)->count() > 0) {` Break it into 2 lines and dump the output of the same?

Comment: Just tried that but, as I already said, I can't even see `dd(...)` output. That method wont be called until the button is pressed but it isn't even loaded.

Comment: can you attach your whole `web.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, if someone in the future has this same problem, I literally just deleted and made manually thee controller, model and blade and it started to work. Not a lot of science or explain, sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `route` to named ones

```
Route::GET('/skills/add', 'SkillsController@addIndex')->name('addSkills');
Route::POST('/skills/add', 'SkillsController@add')->name('saveSkills');
```

and your blade to

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <h1>Edit Skill</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('saveSkills')"> //** Change this
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                     Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">    //** Change this
                </div>
            </div>

            //Remaining form groups

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Skill</button>
                <a href="/skills"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Change your anchor tag's href value to named route like

```
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" href="{{route('addSkills')}}">
    <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>
    Add
</a>
```

and your controller

```
// SHOW ADD NEW SKILL FORM
public function addIndex() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('skills.add');  //view path is skills->add.blade.php
    } else {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}

//SAVE ADD NEW SKILL FORM DATA
public function add(Request $request) {

    dd($request->name); //Check if value is getting

    /*Sets validation rules for Skill object*/
    $skillRules = [
        'name' => 'required|max:25|regex:/[1-9a-zA-Z ]\w*/',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::validate($request->all(), $skillRules);

    if (Skills::where('name', '=', $request->name)->count() > 0) {
        return redirect('/skills')->with('message', "EXISTS");
    }

    if ($validator == null) {
        $newSkill = new Skills;
        $newSkill->name = strtolower($request->name);
        $newSkill->save();
        return redirect('/skills')->with('message', "CREATED");
    }
}
```

also add `use App\RampUp\Skills;` on top of controller

Comment: Just did it. Still nothing.

Comment: So when you click on that ADD link, you get this error page? or when you are submittin the form?

Comment: When you click the add link(the anchor). Let me edit the question to clarify that, my bad.

Comment: Are you trying to update an EXISTING SKILL or ADD NEW SKILL ENTRY in your form?

Comment: The form in `add.skills` is to add a new skill entry.

Comment: Then why are you using put method ? I'll update the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153056/discussion-between-carlos-f-and-sreejith-bs).

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but there is no `POST`-route for `<form method="POST" action="/skills/add">`
maybe the POST is still executed.

On the other hand most `Route` errors could be resolved by clearing the cache (if present), rearranging the routes or put a group in between like

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'skills'], function() {
   Route::put('/add', 'SkillsController@add');

   Route::get('/add', 'SkillsController@addIndex');
  }
```

Comment: thats what `{{method_field('PUT')}}` is for, right? for laravel to cast it as a PUT so it searched for the put route(that works in all the other routes I use it that way). Already trying rearranging and clearing cache and still shows the error.

Comment: @Soundz he intended to use PUT method, that's the way to do it.